# Strange issue with using a keystore

Tags: java

I have a simple program which accesses an url and grabs the data. It uses ssl. I get an handshake_failure when I have not specified any keystore but I do see that it's using the default keystore. The moment I configure it to use the default store explicitly, it works.

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_13.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","changeit") ;
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_13.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts") ;
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","changeit") ;
```

Does anybody know why it work in the above scenario ?

Comment: The file you specified as a KeyStore isn't a KeyStore. It's a truststore. Try it without the first two lines.

Comment: Get the same error....I thought truststore and keystore are the same thing.